# compile java program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I have problem compiling this java file. I cant understand what that problem is. Eclipse says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at ll.ln.main(ln.java:11)"
```

here is the directory:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
package ll;
public class ln {
    public static void main(String arguments[]) {
        String[] pharse={"here i am ","ther you are",
                                 "nobody movewho is in charge here",
                                 "haven dosent far away"};
        for (int count=0;count<=pharse.length;count ++){
            String courenttext=pharse[count];
            char[] chcs=courenttext.toCharArray();
            int[] ln=new int[26];
            for(int i=0;i<=chcs.length;i++){
                if((chcs[i]>'z')||(chcs[i]<'a'))
                 continue;
                ln[chcs[i]-'a'] ++;
            }
            for (int i=0;i<27;i++){
                char t='a';
                t+=i;
                System.out.println(t +": "+ln[i]+"   ");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mismatching the String and .toCharArray(); what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in each of these lines replace `<=`  with `<` :

```
for (int count=0;count<=pharse.length;count ++){
```

should be:

```
for (int count=0;count<pharse.length;count ++){
```

in this line also :

```
for(int i=0;i<=chcs.length;i++){
```

should be :

```
for(int i=0;i<chcs.length;i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<` instead of `<=`

```
for (int i = 0; i < chcs.length; i++)
```

Complete code

```
        String[] pharse = { "here i am ", "ther you are", "nobody movewho is in charge here",
                "haven dosent far away" };
        for (int count = 0; count < pharse.length; count++) {
            String courenttext = pharse[count];
            char[] chcs = courenttext.toCharArray();
            int[] ln = new int[26];
            for (int i = 0; i < chcs.length; i++) {
                if ((chcs[i] > 'z') || (chcs[i] < 'a'))
                    continue;
                ln[chcs[i] - 'a']++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                char t = 'a';
                t += i;
                System.out.println(t + ": " + ln[i] + "   ");

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for(int i=0;i<=chcs.length;i++)
```

To

```
for(int i=0;i<chcs.length;i++)
```

Your index exceeds the length

Answer (score 0):

Change 3 lines:

1. `for (int count=0;count<=pharse.length;count ++){`

   to

   `for (int count=0;count<pharse.length;count ++){`
2. `for(int i=0;i<=chcs.length;i++){`

   to

   `for(int i=0;i<chcs.length;i++){`
3. `for (int i=0;i<27;i++){`

   to

   `for (int i=0;i<26;i++){`